# Button in Excel file to refresh data from file on WordPress using (username, password) using VBA

Tags: wordpress, vba, excel

I've Excel file with button in sheet under which data is to be loaded from the file at WordPress website. I've implemented this VBA cide but it directly download from link even without any credentials.

```
Sub DownloadFile()
Dim myURL As String
myURL = "http://www. **.com/wp-content/uploads/ExportFiles/data.xlsx"
Dim username As Variant
Dim password As Variant
username = InputBox("Enter Username")
password = InputBox("Enter Password")

Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False, username, password
WinHttpReq.send

myURL = WinHttpReq.responseBody
If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then 
     Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
     oStream.Open
     oStream.Type = 1
     oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
     oStream.SaveToFile "E:\data.xlsx", 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 overwrite
     oStream.Close
End If

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim filter As String
Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook, wb As Workbook
Dim Ret As Variant

Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook


'If Ret = False Then Exit Sub
Ret = "E:\data.xlsx"
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Ret)

wb.Sheets(1).Move After:=targetWorkbook.Sheets(targetWorkbook.Sheets.Count)

ActiveSheet.Name = "DATA"
```

End Sub

Comment: What is the question / problem?

Comment: Problem is it is extracting data from website even if credentials are wrong...

Comment: I want to control login from this VBA from Excel, to WordPress to download file